# comma before "that is" and how to convey definition vs. additional information

Tags: commas

> We are looking for an electric car, **that is,** a car that runs on electricity.
>
> We are looking for an electric car **that is** red.

How do I distinguish between these two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is used to mimic the pause that would occur if a sentence was spoken out loud.   When redefining the previous information, there is a conversational pause:

> Grandfather called her a "young girl" **, that is,** anyone under the age of 60, in his opinion.

When simply modifying the previous information, there is no pause:

> Grandfather called her a "young girl" **who is** no more than 60 years old.

However, it is not uncommon to add a comma before "that is" even when modifying, although with slightly different phrasing:

> I'm looking for a new car **, one that is** red.

There is no clear line between what is "additional information" and what is "description".  We have to determine *from context* whether the information after the subject is important or incidental.

Comment: Is there a general convention, this is going to be incredibly confusing once you get technical.  e.g.  S is a compact set, that is closed and bounded.

Comment: @HaoS  The conversational pause tells the listener that you are *redefining* the subject in some way.  If there is no pause, then it's an adjectival phrase modifying the subject.   Again, there is no other way of knowing this without the pause and the surrounding context.  In your example, I would not have used a comma because it sounds like modification, *"S is a compact set that is closed and bounded"*.   Perhaps you are overthinking this distinction?

Comment: It's not a modifications closed and bounded is synonymous/defining compact  

Thats why I'm overthinking this distinction  once your in a technical/scientific... etc situation this becomes quite a problem.